# Is Service Fabric hybrid on premise and internet exposed solution currently possible?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a series of WebApi self hostable services that I need to make available both on-premise and the internet. Currently they are only on-premise, but I was wondering will service fabric allow me to have an on premise cluster and azure hosted cluster connected and handle this hybrid scenario? Can I have a service fabric cluster with nodes both on premise and in azure?

I have it on my backlog to explore leveraging service fabric, but if this scenario was available we would bump up that priority.

Any details on implementing this or even an alternative solution would be greatly appreciated. We tried using Azure App Proxy as well for the internet exposure, but are having problems with the authentication headers going across as we are not using Azure AD.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a cluster that spans multiple locations. Like mentioned [this](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/deploy-a-geo-ha-service-fabric-cluster-on-azure/) article.

However you should realize that it's not a supported feature. If you make a mistake, loosing one of two locations will result in data loss.

I'd recommend using one cluster.

Comment: Thank you for the info, this got me pointed towards the info/terminology to get me on the right path.